# On premises gateway PowerBI Service

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, onpremises-gateway

I'm trying to connect my datasource in power bi service via my on-premises gateway. The on-premises gateway is working perfectly in Powerapps with no connection problems. This is the screen I get to connect them:

[image]

When I add to gateway I fill in the data and so on:

[image]

When I connect with the port behind it I don't get a connection to the SQL. If I delete the port and I connect I get a connection in SQL. But then the connection string is this: be-gbdps006\sqlexpress and not be-gbdps006\sqlexpress:1433 so I still can't add it to the Gateway. Does someone has a solution to solve this. (also I need this port in power bi desktop otherwise I can't get connected to the SQL and I can't publish it) I hope someone had the same issue and does have solved someway.

Comment: Normally you'd use either the instance name `BE-GBDPS006\SQLEXPRESS` or you'd use the port number `BE-GBDPS006,1433` (note the comma, I think only the JDBC driver uses the colon separator), not both together. Default installations of SQL Server Express usually don't listen on a TCP port and, even when they are, they're usually listening on a dynamic port that's not 1433. Have you used SQL Server Configuration Manager to make your Express instances behave otherwise?

Comment: Hello I used the comma on both and it worked, thank you very much!